# How to click hCAPTCHA checkbox with php-webdriver in PHP?

Tags: php, selenium, facebook-php-webdriver

I have this code with php-webdriver library in Selenium to click hCAPTCHA's checkbox square button but results to an error instead. See code below...

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);

$driver->get('https://accounts.hcaptcha.com/demo?sitekey=f5561ba9-8f1e-40ca-9b5b-a0b3f719ef34');

print ($driver->getTitle());
    
$iframe = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("/html/body/div[5]/form/fieldset/ul/li[2]/div/div/iframe"));  
$driver->switchTo()->frame($iframe);    

$checkbox = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div'));
$checkbox->click();
```

But results to an error below...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the step `$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div'));` we are specifying to search element by id but we are passing the `absoulte xpath` for the element

You need to pass the `id` of the captcha to click on it

Your solution would look like

```
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
$driver->get('https://accounts.hcaptcha.com/demo?sitekey=f5561ba9-8f1e-40ca-9b5b-a0b3f719ef34');
print ($driver->getTitle());
$iframe = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("/html/body/div[5]/form/fieldset/ul/li[2]/div/div/iframe"));  
$driver->switchTo()->frame($iframe);    
$driver->wait(5, 500)->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#checkbox')));
$checkbox =  $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('#checkbox'));  
$checkbox->click();
```

Comment: I tried the code suggested above but still got this error, "**Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"checkbox"} (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.66) (Driver info: chromedriver=103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd74ff1cf2150f36ffa3b0dae40b17f-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#853}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.20348 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)**".

Comment: Hi @gprialde updated the solution the captcha element sometimes takes time to load on the page so we need to check for presence of element using webdriver wait . Can you retry

Comment: Hi @gprialde can you check the above  update solution

Comment: Yes I have done it and it works. Thanks!